# Why php PDO sign in is not working?

Tags: php, pdo

Im trying to sign in with PDO but I cant. When I'm trying with old database connection it works, but with PDO its not; I cant understand where exactly is the issue, connection is OK but the code is not navigating to other page, Email and passwords are correct.Please see the mail below and if you can help me.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=social", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

class UserLogin {

    public $id;
    public $first;
    public $last;
    public $email;
    public $password;

    function Login(){
        global $conn;
        $this->email = $_POST['user_email'];
        $this->password = $_POST['user_email'];
        $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM scusers WHERE scemail =? AND scpass =?");
        $sql->execute(array($this->email, $this->password));
        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $this->email = $row['scemail'];
            $this->password = $row['scpass'];
        }

    }

}

<?php
//print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['user_email']) && isset($_POST['user_password'])){
    $login = new UserLogin();
    $login->email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $login->password = $_POST['user_password'];
    if($login->Login()){
        header("Location:home.php");
    }else{
        echo "Negative";
    }
}
?>
  <body>
<header>

            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="user_email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                                <div class="login-bottom-text checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="">

                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="user_password" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                <div class="login-bottom-text"><a class="bottom-txt" href="recover_password.php">Forgot your password?</a></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" value=" Send" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: `Login()` method has no `return` statement.

Comment: and in `Login` you assign `$_POST['user_email']` to `$this->password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Login()` method has no return statement. Without `return` statement function returns `NULL`. `NULL` is obvioulsy considered **falsy**. So, change `Login()` method so it returns some **truthy** value, at least this way:

```
function Login(){
    $user_found = false;

    global $conn;
    $this->email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $this->password = $_POST['user_email'];   // is it?
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM scusers WHERE scemail =? AND scpass =?");
    $sql->execute(array($this->email, $this->password));
    while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $this->email = $row['scemail'];
        $this->password = $row['scpass'];

        $user_found = true;
    }

    return $user_found;
}
```

Comment: Exactly, stupid mistake, also Jeff mentioned above. Im really tired

Answer (score 1):

This code block will always echo 'Negative' because method Login doesn't return anything

```
    if($login->Login()){
        header("Location:home.php");
    }else{
        echo "Negative";
    }
```

It should return true in case of finding a row in the database.